# Deconstructing Message from an IMarker

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Since I needed to get the error message from a given marker, I made a call to `MarkerUtilities.getMessage(myMarker)` It would be fine but the problem is it only returns a String such as something like this: `The method x() is undefined for the type A`
Is there a structure where I can find the error in an XML-like or tree-like format:

```
<Problem>Method Undefined</Problem>
<Method>X()</Method>
<Type>A</Type>
```

I want to treat those as separate objects and don't want to use string concatenation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I suppose that you are _not_ just talking about `IMarker` objects you have created yourself, but also about the markers created by JDT?

Comment: @TonnyMadsen I'm talking about the markers created by JDT. My code is listening to any change in a .java file via IResourceChangeListener and I am interested in any kind of error that the markers are reporting. with getMessage I only get a string and I was wondering if there is another way to x() and A without having to parse the string.

Comment: Then you're out of luck, as JDT only reports the text itself - it is not broken up into the parts/structure you wish for...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Thanks. Looks like I would have to tap to the compiler and see when it is reporting the errors. I'm sure the markers created by JDT made a call to setMessage() (although at that time I don't know if it's feasible to tap to JDT's compiler)

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement IMarker and make your own marker that has it's message stored in XML or in a Tree, that you will get back a message in the format you want, or can create a method on your marker to give you the message back in any format you want.

IBM Developerworks has a quick tutorial about creating your own Marker, and Eclipse has the documentation for the IMarker interface:

[IBM Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-plugin-guide/section2.html)
[Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Ftexteditor%2FMarkerUtilities.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already looked into those but they are not really satisfying what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about `IMakers`/messages from JDT, you will have to split it up yourself. The message set by JDT is just a text string (based on NLS). So unfortunately, you're out of luck.